# Getting assembly information in .NET framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I have a setup of crystal reports installed in 32-bit OS and 64-bit OS,

```
in 32-bit it installs in SOFTWARE location under HKEY_LOCALMACHINE.

in 64-bit it installs in SOFTWARE\WOw6432Node location under HKEY_LOCALMACHINE
```

How do i load assemblies without specifying the path ?

ie. I don't want to do like this

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assemblyInfo = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Engine.dll");
```

The Engine.dll can be anywhere not specifically inside the program files.

> Is there some thing in .NET framework i can use to make framework to
>   load assembly information, when i supply the .dll name alone? (internally framework can search it
>   and load the assembly information).

I don't think GetTypeFromProgID might help.

Answer (score 0):

For an assembly namespaces to be globally accessible you need to place an assembly into a GAC.

[How to: Install an Assembly into the Global Assembly Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx)

Comment: Crystal Reports should already install itself in the GAC - check C:\Windows\Assembly

Comment: That's correct, can't i get from there the assembly info like token GUID , version etc or create an instance of that assembly?

Answer (score 0):

set it in gac

```
gacutil.exe -I <assembly name>
```